# Refreshing page in react

Tags: reactjs

I created a modal if the user click refresh. Now I want to use my created modal instead of the default prompt as seen on the image. I want to show the modal that I created instead of the default prompt.

[image]

This is my code:

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
const [refreshPage, setRefreshPage] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
 const unloadCallback = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = "";
  setShowModal(true);
}
if (refreshPage) {
  window.location.reload();
} else {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
}

return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
}, [refreshPage])

const handleCloseModal = () => {
 setShowModal(false);
}

const handleRefreshClick = () => {
  setRefreshPage(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you improve your post? What do you want exactly to achieve?

Comment: Where is the modal that you created?

Comment: you can't delete standart modal window for event 'beforeunload' and create your own. The only option is to look at the cursor position near the close button and create your own modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can't fully replace the browser's default "beforeunload". The  browser imposes restrictions to prevent potentially malicious behaviour. Specifically, you can't suppress the browser's default prompt and show your own UI instead because the beforeunload event doesn't permit it.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest this implementation:

here you can use a custom modal,  by replacing the div with a custom component, or by adding some CSS

feel free then to add the on effect and all you need,
I don't have enough informations in your code to provide you a better answer

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleOpenModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  }

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  }

  const handleRefreshClick = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOpenModal}>Refresh</button>

      {showModal && (
        <div>
          {/* This is your modal code */}
          <p>Are you sure you want to refresh?</p>
          <button onClick={handleRefreshClick}>Yes, Refresh</button>
          <button onClick={handleCloseModal}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```